# Latex class: how to change line space, font, font size, margin

Tags: luatex, document-classes

- I have a document class that I am using for writing my thesis. Here is the documentclass in this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X27izFUmZrJmwOqiYCmZY3eW63DlxCpJ/view?usp=sharing).
- I also have a paper that is written using the document class IEEEtran. I can compile my latex and get the PDF. However, the font, line spaces, margin, font size, etc. of the paper differ from those of the thesis.

I would like to change the parameters mentioned above to those of the thesis.

Does anybody know how to do that?

best

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just change the class from IEEEtran to the one you want for your thesis?

Comment: The document class for the thesis is for writing a thesis, not a paper. However, to be consistent in font size, font style, line spacing, etc. I want the mentioned parameters in the paper to be the same as those in the thesis.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not submitting the paper to any journal at the moment. The paper was earlier written for a journal. But, now I want to attach it to the introduction of my thesis. So, it is odd if the introduction of the thesis has a font and size and the paper has another font and size. That is why I wanted to unify.

Comment: oh you are going from ieee to the thesis style sorry I read tha backwards, why not simply include the body of the paper as a chapter of your thesis?

Comment: Good point. Now how to find the font style, font size, line spacing, margin setting, etc. in the thesis document class and set all these parameters in the article. I have attached the documentclass of thesis. Could you have a look?

Comment: but I don't understand why you don't simply set the text as a chapter in your thesis so it automatically gets the same style? why do you need it as a separate document that looks like your thesis? (no sorry I'm not following external links)

Comment: Because the paper has an abstract, sub chapters, equation numbers. If I put as a chapter in the thesis all these will change or even not showing properly. Therefore, I try to generate the PDF of the paper and put the PDF in the thesis.

Comment: David's suggestion is the best, import the text only. You can minimize the errors by using the package IEEEtrantools in the preamble. Comment any remaining sections that give problems and these can then be emulated by writing special commands. It will also lead to better overall typography, spacing etc.

Comment: no, that does not work for me.